# Detecting from within a process whether it is running as an HTCondor job

Tags: python, c++, condor

Could you please let me know if there is a way to detect from within a process whether it is running as an [HTCondor](https://htcondor.org/htcondor/overview/) job?

I am especially interested in how to do it from python code but a C++ way to do it would be also very helpful.

Example of what I hope to do in python:

```py
if current_process_is_running_as_an_HTCondor_job():
    do_action_1()
else:
    do_action_2()
```

How can one implement `current_process_is_running_as_an_HTCondor_job()` ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Without looking at their documentation I'd guess they set one or more environment variables that you could look for

Comment: Thank you, Alan! You are right: https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-manual/services-for-jobs.html If you submit it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTCondor sets a number of environment variables: https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-manual/services-for-jobs.html

- `_CONDOR_SCRATCH_DIR`
- `_CONDOR_SLOT`
- `_CONDOR_JOB_AD`
- `_CONDOR_MACHINE_AD`
- `_CONDOR_JOB_IWD`
- `_CONDOR_WRAPPER_ERROR_FILE`

The existence of any of them would be a good indicator that you are running under Condor.